# Laravel Auditing package working only on User model and not working on other models

Tags: laravel

If I try to put on another model only new created record is auditing. Update, delete is not working.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;


class Brands extends Model implements Auditable

{

    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    use Notifiable;

    use HasRoles;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

   protected $fillable = [

        'brand_name', 'brand_status'

    ];

    protected $auditInclude  = [

        'brand_name', 'brand_status'

    ];


}
```

I don't know why in User model it is tracking all events. But in another model, only the newly created record is tracking and not other things like deleting, updating it is not tracking.

Comment: corrected answer is not a valid answer, I tried multiple times. how did you solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `config/audit.php` , make sure that the `timestamps` setting is set to `true`. This allows the `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` timestamps to be audited.

```
'timestamps' => true,
```

EDIT: Add `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` inside your `protected $auditInclude` fuunction

```
protected $auditInclude  = [
    'brand_name', 'brand_status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'
];
```

Comment: Try again, after you clear cache. You need to always clear cache when you update config files. Use these commands: `php artisan config:cache` , `php artisan cache:clear` , `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I have tried all 3 commands still it is not working. Any trait we have to use in the controller?

Comment: not working. If I add a new record then it is working only update and delete is not working

Comment: Only updated_at is working? Maybe you misspelled other columns names. You also said when you "add a new record" deleted_at is not working. Try to delete that record and see if it works. Of course deleted isn't working when you're adding a new record.

Comment: No only created is working.update and delete not working

Comment: Delete the record you just created, then deleted_at will work.

Comment: No problem man. Mark it as an answer, so it can help users in future who could have similar problems.